# z index and click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

So i have this three column layout. http://jsfiddle.net/quickburp/fwQq4/50/  ..

Now, if you click on the div with id "left" no alert is triggered. This is because the div with class wrapper is above it.   Even the css property cursor:pointer on div#left is not functioning because of this.

I have tried z-index..

How can I get the left and right div above the wrapper. And get the cursor:pointer to work and the click events to work

Comment: I suppose, that the `position: fixed;` of `.wrapper` is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `z-index: 0;` from `.wrapper {}`